# Special Characters in password causing Basic Auth Failure in Mojolicious UA

Tags: perl, mojolicious

The following program fails when trying to go to an https web site that requires basic authentication.

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgen->new;

my $user = "foobar";
my $pass = "Cant#change";

my $url  = "https://$user:$pass\@site.foo.com";
my $tx   = $ua->get($url);

if (my $res = $tx->success) {
    say $res->body;
}
else {
    my ($message, $code) = $tx->error;
    say $code ? "$code response $message" : "Connection error: $message";
}
```

When I run with MOJO_USERAGENT_DEBUG=1 I get the following output:

```
-- Blocking request (https://foobar:cant#change@site.foo.com)
-- Connect (https:foobar:Cant:443)
Connection error: Couldn't connect
```

Using Mojolicious 3.35 updated from CPAN.  Unfortunately, passwords will likely contain "special characters" (ascii #!@%^& and the like) and changing the password to something not containing a # is not an option.  The web server handles the request correctly in web browsers, so I do not believe it is a web server configuration issue.

So is there another way to achieve this in Mojo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is yours, not Mojo's. Specifically, the URL is incorrectly built. Fix:

```
use URI::Escape qw( uri_escape );
my $creds = uri_escape($user) . ':' . uri_escape($pass);
my $url  = 'https://' . $creds . '@site.foo.com/';
```

Comment: Yes, uri_escaping fixes this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```perl
use Mojo::Base -strict;
use Mojo::URL;

#1 Mojo way
my $url = Mojo::URL->new('http://google.com/')->userinfo('user:pa#ss');
say $url;


#2 or manually
use Mojo::Util qw/url_escape/;

my $auth = join ':', url_escape('user'), url_escape('pa#ss');

my $url2 = qq{http://$auth\@google.com/};
say $url2;
```